# Not inserting values to database:

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make Sign Up Now! area for a restaurant website and want to insert data of new members in the `members_t` table of database `members` with all running on `localhost`. I am using PHP and HTML for the purpose. Moreover, I am doing form validation using javaScript in a separate file which is working perfectly!

Code for PHP:

```
<?php
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="members";
$con = mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$password);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die( "Unable to select database");
if(isset($_POST['sign_up']) && !empty($_POST['sign_up']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members_t('Name', 'Email', 'Password', 'Phone', 'Address', 'Sex', 'More') VALUES('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['passid_1']."','".$_POST['zip']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['sex']."','".$_POST['desc']."');";
    $resultDI = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
    echo "Successfolly run database query!";
}
else 
{
    echo("Failed to update database!!!");
}
?>
```

Code for HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 class="letter_spacing">Not a Member?<span><br>Sign Up Now:</br></span></h2>
<form id = "register" name="registration" method = "post" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
<ul>
<li><label for="username">* Full Name:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="username" size="50" /></li>
<li><label for="email">* Email:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></li>
<li><label for="passid_1">* Desired Password:</label></li>
<li><input type="password" name="passid_1" size="12" /></li>
<li><label for="passid_2">* Re-Enter Password:</label></li>
<li><input type="password" name="passid_2" size="12" /></li>
<li><label for="zip">* Contact Number:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="zip" /></li>
<li><label for="address">* Address:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="address" size="50" /></li>
<li><label id="gender">* Sex:</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="msex" value="Male" /><span>Male</span></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="fsex" value="Female" /><span>Female</span></li>
<li><label for="desc">Anything More:</label></li>
<li><textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea></li>
<li><label for="note" ><h6>Note: All feilds marked with * are necessary</h6></label></li>
<li><input class="button1" type="submit"  name="sign_up" value="Sign Up!" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to keep the code in a separate file called insert.php and added the action field to the HTML form tag yet of no use.

I am never able to insert data into the database. It seems the PHP code never goes into the

```
if(isset($_POST['sign_up']) && !empty($_POST['sign_up']))
```

block.

Comment: First of all, you simply need to reduce `if(isset($_POST['sign_up']) && !empty($_POST['sign_up']))` to `if(isset($_POST['signup']))` or `if ($_POST['sign_up'])`

Comment: @pekka using `or die(mysql_error())` is a perfectly acceptable way to show an error.  If it fails, the mysql_error() will be displayed on the page...

Comment: I think that we need to see your JavaScript code to see how that would affect the submitting of the data to your PHP code.  Does your JavaScript actually submit your code to the PHP file?  Because your form isn't set to via an `action=""` attribute.

Comment: @Pekka I agree with what you're saying, yes.  But for testing purposes like this it should be fine.  It is valid advice though.

Comment: @Coulton I overlooked that he's already using `mysql_error()` after the query. Now I get what you mean. Mea culpa, deleting my comments

Comment: Be aware that your SQL is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should **always** either escape or (much better) bind the variables, not simply concatenate them into a string.

Comment: @user188 are you sure, you have added the action attribute to html form tag. I don't see it in the code. Put some echo statements above the if to verify, if the execution is going there or not ?

Comment: Like @Kitsune said, you're open to SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives examples of how to properly use parametrized queries.

Comment: Thanks guys! I tried to use action="post" and made use of PHP in a separate file: The javaScript code is written below!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="register" action="" method="post" name="registration" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
    <input type="text" name="username" size="50" />
    <input type="text" name="email" size="50" />
    <input type="password" name="passid_1" size="12" />
    <input type="password" name="passid_2" size="12" />
    <input type="text" name="zip" />
    <input type="text" name="address" size="50" />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" /><span>Male</span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" /><span>Female</span>
    <textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input class="button1" type="submit"  name="sign_up" value="Sign Up!" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['sign_up']) && !empty($_POST['sign_up'])) {
    // escape all submitted data before inserting into database
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($value));
    }

    $result = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO members_t (Name, Email, Password, Phone, Address, Sex, More)
        VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['passid_1']}', '{$_POST['zip']}', '{$_POST['address']}', '{$_POST['sex']}', '{$_POST['desc']}')
    ") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
        echo "Successfully run database query!";
    } else {
        echo("Failed to update database!!!");
    }
}
?>
```

Note that name of the `radio` buttons should be the same "sex" not "msex" and "fsex" as in your code. And I have added the `action` attribute in the `form` tag plus some other modifications you can easily notice.

Comment: I gave radio buttons different names so that I could check in javaScript if both are not checked. Is there a way in html that allows checking of one out of several radio buttons in a group?

Comment: Make the male is the default sex using "checked" with the male radio button like this: <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked /> . This way you will be sure that at least one of them (male or female) is checked. And if the user is a female then she will check the female radio button instead

Comment: Code not working for PHP let me try to make some changes and check it error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Name', 'Email', 'Password', 'Phone', 'Address', 'Sex', 'More') VALUES('asdf','a' at line 1

Comment: The code ran successfully first one of the above mentioned codes with minor changes!
If you are using MySQL v-5.5.8 don't use database field attributes in single quotes rather use them as they are. Like you should write Name instead of 'Name' in attributes list.

Thanks a lot once again all of you...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i have cleaned up the code a little so it looks nice and smooth. Then i have removed the !empty part you made, cant see the reason why you want to verify that it actually is empty when you already used isset.
HTML:

```
<?php
$hostname = "";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "members";

$desc = $_POST['desc'];

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $password);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die( "Unable to select database");
if(isset($_POST['sign_up']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The username is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The email is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['zip'])){
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The zip code is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['address'])){
        $address = $_POST['address'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The gender is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['sex'])){
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The gender is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['passid_1'])){
        $passid = $_POST['passid_1'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The password is not set"; die;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['passid_2'])){
        $passid2 = $_POST['passid_2'];
    }
    else {
        echo "The re-entered password is not set"; die;
    }

    if($passwid == $passid2){
        $correctpid = $passwid;
    }
    else {
        echo "The passwords do not match"; die;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members_t('Name', 'Email', 'Password', 'Phone', 'Address', 'Sex', 'More') VALUES('$username', '$email','$correctpid', '$zip', '$address', '$sex', '$desc');";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
    echo "Successfolly run database query!";
}
else 
{
    echo("Failed to update database!!!");
}
?>
```

I have made the php code to check if all the fields are filled with data. If not the site die and gives them a error message. It kills the website before it can set anything into the database.

-- I made some more changes to the code after comments, thanks btw.

Comment: All your checks like `if(isset($username))` will ALWAYS return `true` since the variables are defined and initialized on top of the script (just after "// data:"). You don't need empty code blocks, use the negation instead: `if(!isset($some_variable)) { do something here }`

Comment: you need to fix lines 8 to 15: how can you be sure that `$_POST['username']`, `$_POST['email']`...are actually set?

Comment: @Jocelyn thanks again, i have made a bit more changes to the code, can you please look it through?

Comment: I have used javaScript for form validation it never allows submitting the form unless all fields are filled, is that enough or I need to check it on server side too?

Comment: @user18889654 People can still copy your form down to their own pc and send data to the php file where it will check the data again. So i would recommend to use both :-)